# How to pass an object as parameter from android to web service using ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to send object as parameter to web service on java. It always throws a Runtime exception with Cannot serialize
what is the best way to do that
thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [Complex Objects with Ksoap2](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)
Essentially, the only thing you have to do is implement the `KvmSerializable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Like as Ksoap2's page in google code, [CodingTipsAndTricks](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request) part:
To get this xml:

```
<users>
  <user>
     <name>Jonh</name>
     <age>12</age>
  </user>
  <user>
     <name>Marie</name>
     <age>27</age>
  </user>
</users>
```

You would do this:

```
SoapObject users = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "users");
SoapObject john = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "john");
john.addProperty("age", 12);
SoapObject marie = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "user");
john.addProperty("name", "marie");
john.addProperty("age", 27);
users.addSoapObject(john);
users.addSoapObject(marie);
```